# Backtick Execution Works Locally But Not On Server

Tags: ruby, cucumber, sinatra

Here's a simple sinatra app that displays the results of a cucumber run in the browser:

```rb
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
    `cucumber features --format html`
end

get '/ls' do
    `ls`
end
```

The root route works fine, and does what I want on my local machine: It executes cucumber and shows the results.  The problem is that on my server I get the error `No such file or directory - cucumber features --format html`.

*Troubleshooting I've Done So Far*

- Ran the `ls` route.  It works both locally and on the server, and shows results from the directory I expect in both cases -- the same directory the sinatra app runs in.
- Ran `cucumber features --format html` from the command line over ssh on the server.  Again, it works fine and the output is what I expect.

So why am I getting the error when I run it through sinatra using ruby's backticks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure cucumber is installed on the server? If so, and it was installed via bundler, try changing the command to this:

```
bundle exec cucumber ...
```

**Edit**

Turns out cucumber was not in the path. Solution is to use the full path to cucumber.

Comment: as i said in the op, running cucumber from the command line over ssh works fine, so it must be installed on the server.  also, i know because i installed it :)  it was not installed via bundler, but simply with a `gem install cucumber`

Comment: Interesting. Are you using rvm or rbenv, and is it possible the gem bin folder isn't in the path for the server's shell? Easiest way to check is to print the $PATH from the server.

Comment: This is the problem.  It's on my path but not on the path of the web server.  Thanks Tanzeeb!